# IE8 renders in compatibility view with meta tag

Tags: internet-explorer-8, ie8-compatibility-mode

I know this is an issue that comes up a lot, but I can't find an answer:

My site loads by default on IE8 in compatibility view.
I tried putting the

`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` tag, but with no use. the document mode is IE8, but the browser mode stay on compatibility.

I also tried:
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">`
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8,9,10,11">`
`<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Emulate8">`

I also have the following doctype:

`<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 TRANSITIONAL//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.
I entered the site from our Intranet, and IE opens all sites on the local intranet (except for localhost) in Compatibility View.